# Set read status for a group chat using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to make a chat application containing individual chat between users and group chat using Firebase. And I would like to make a read status for each message, Now the problem is, consider a group chat have a node

```
> groupId---->
>         --->messageId
>                  -->userId
>                  -->messageType
>                  -->text
```

My implimentation is like if a user sending a message to a group that will be added under group id with message id node and who are all listening to the group will get that child message now I want to keep a status for who are all read the message. I can handle it by keeping a local status, But if the user logging from another device how can I handle that?

Comment: You have to make a boolean under messageID Node, that keeps the record of Read status

Comment: If group having more members its not possible right?

Comment: I am also implementing the same functionality in my app. I have implemented single user chat but i am facing issues in group chat. Could you sent me the database schema of your app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to track whether a user had read each message, you'll need to store that in your database:

```
read_messages_per_user
  <userId>
    <messageId>: true
```

This may become a lot of data over time. So a more efficient (but less specific) variant is to store the *last message that the user read*.

```
last_read_messageId_per_user
  <userId>: <messageId>
```